# Can a Mozilla/GoogleChrome Plugin written in C++ be decompiled?

Tags: google-chrome, npapi, xpcom, native-code

I have some proprietary algorithm that I want to use it on the client side for which I zeroed on doing it in C++ ( using XPCOM in Mozilla and Native Code in Google Chrome ) compared to doing it in Javascript.
Can I be sure that it would be very very difficult to decompile ( although possible ) the plugin compared to that for Java and Javascript

Answer (score 2):

Any compiled C++ code can be disassembled. There is for example [The Interactive Disassembler](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) which does a pretty good job to visualize the logic of a disassembled application and simplify understanding the code. Somebody who has disassembling experience won't have any problem digging up any secrets you might want to hide in this code - if that's what you are asking. Generally, hiding any secrets on the client side is a bad idea.

Btw, a note: you [shouldn't use binary XPCOM components](http://adblockplus.org/blog/binary-xpcom-components-are-dead-js-ctypes-is-the-way-to-go), use [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes) instead which will be simpler in all respects.